# express.js https server noob

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, express

Using node.js with express I've made a simple https server. For testing purposes I've made a basic login form that gets posted to this https server.

My expectation was that by simply doing:

```
var app = require('../app');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

// I used openssl to generate a ssl certificate
var pkey = fs.readFileSync('key.pem');
var pcert = fs.readFileSync('cert.pem');

var options = {
    key: pkey,
    cert: pcert
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);

httpsServer.listen(8081, 'localhost');
```

that data posted to `/login` would be properly encrypted:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body); // this is the post data sent from client
});
```

I expected `req.body` to look like 'encrypted' data as I have no middleware decrypting anything, but instead I got `{name: 'abc', 'password': '123'}`. Am I missing a step in this process or does the node `https` module handle all of encryption/decryption stuff? Or am I completely missing the picture on what https is used for/does?

Comment: You need to read on how the `https` works and what is it

Comment: @Vsevolod Goloviznin I could certainly read more on the topic. Although I was not clear about it, my question is more about the node `https` module or maybe https servers in general. My understanding is that the server gets the encrypted data from the client and uses the agreed upon cypher suite with the proper keys to reassemble the data. What I'm looking for is confirmation that this decryption process is handled within the `https` module and that it occurs as the first step in the server side flow.

Comment: Yes, it decrypts the data first, that's why you don't get some random values in your router method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP talks over some sort of communication channel. TLS is a protocol that allows you to construct a secure communication channel over an insecure communication channel. HTTPS is TLS wrapped around HTTP. From your application’s point of view (using the TLS communication channel), everything will be in plaintext, since TLS is handling all of the encryption and decryption for you.